# CakePHPにおけるFacebook認証について

Tags: php, cakephp, facebook

CakePHPにおいてFacebookでログインを開発しているのですがうまくいきません。

基本的に下記サイトを利用しました。

http://shigurui.kirscheweb.com/?p=136

前提として

- モデル：User
- コントローラ：UsersController.php

`app_id`と`app_secret`は取得してセットしてあります。

下記手順で

- 2,5,9番の配置方法
- 3番の`Configure::write('Opauth.path', '/users/auth/');`
- 7番のControllerの記述方法

が怪しいのではないかといくつか試しましたがどれも上手くいきません。

何かアドバイスなどいただければ幸いです。

### 手順

1.下記サイトより`cakephp-opauth-master.zip`をダウンロード

https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-opauth

2.ダウンロードしたファイルを解凍し、CakePHPのプラグインとして下記に設置

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

3.`bootstrap.php`に設定を記入

アプリ/app/Config/bootstrap.php

```
CakePlugin::load('Opauth', array('routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true));

Configure::write('Opauth.Strategy.Facebook', array(
'app_id' => 'YOUR FACEBOOK APP ID',
'app_secret' => 'YOUR FACEBOOK APP SECRET'
));
Configure::write('Opauth.path', '/users/login/');
```

*パスにはただ単にログイン画面を指定した

4.Facebook用の「Strategy」をダウンロード

https://github.com/opauth/facebook

5.ダウンロードしたファイルを解凍し、Strategyとして設置

アプリ/app/Plugin/Opauth/Strategy/Facebook

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

6.`Config/routes.php`に記述を追加

```
Router::connect(
       '/opauth-complete/*', 
       array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'opauth_complete')
   );
```

7.コントローラーにメソッドを追加

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
       public function opauth_complete() {
           debug($this->data);
       }
   }
```

9.ダウンロードしたファイルを解凍し、Vendorに設置

アプリ/vendors/Opauth

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

10.認証URLにアクセス

`http://localhost/アプリ/auth/facebook`

＊アクセス方法は全くわかりません

Comment: 「○○をすると××というエラーが表示される」「○○の意味が理解できない」「○○のやり方がわからない」といった風に、あなたが何に困っているのかを具体的に書いてもらえないでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼しました
質問として
①2,5,9番の配置方法は正しいのか？
②3番のConfigure::write('Opauth.path', '/users/login/');の記述ですが
　/users/login/のところに何を記述すればいいのか？（参考サイトに認証ページと書いてあったのでログインのURLを記述しました）
③ 10番でのアクセス方法
http://サーバ名/users/auth/facebook
と入力すると下記のようなエラーとなります
----------------------------------------------------------------
Not Found

Error: The requested address '/×××/auth/facebook' was not found on this server.
----------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ①2,5,9番の配置方法は正しいのか？

cakephp-opauth、facebook用strategy、opauth、それぞれ問題なく配置できていると思います。

> ②3番の`Configure::write('Opauth.path', '/users/login/');`の記述ですが`/users/login/`のところに何を記述すればいいのか？（参考サイトに認証ページと書いてあったのでログインのURLを記述しました）

cakephp-opauthのreadmeから引用すると、

> If your CakePHP app does not reside at DocumentRoot (eg. http://localhost), but at a directory below DocumentRoot (eg. http://localhost/your-cake-app),
>   add this line to your app's APP/Config/bootstrap.php, replacing your-cake-app with your actual path :

とあるので、あなたのアプリに`http://hogehoge/`としてアクセスできる場合はこのオプションは不要です。`http://hogehoge/someapp/`としてアクセスしている場合は`/someapp/auth/`を指定します。

> ③ 10番でのアクセス方法 `http://サーバ名/users/auth/facebook` と入力すると下記のようなエラーとなります

ここまでの流れから察するに、`http://サーバ名/`でCakePHPのルートにアクセスできるようですから、`http://サーバ名/auth/facebook`になるかと思います。

なお公式のチュートリアルに従うなら、`/auth/`というURLは固定です。これを例えば`/users/auth/`などに変更したい場合は[`app/Plugin/OpAuth/Config/routes.php`](https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-opauth/blob/master/Config/routes.php)を参考に自分でルートを定義する必要があるようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
bootstrap.phpのConfigure::write('Opauth.path', '/users/login/');を消し
http://サーバ名/auth/facebookにアクセスしたところ、認証の画面が表示されました。

しかしOKを押すとhttp://サーバ名/auth/callbackに転送され下記のようにエラーが表示されます。
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Not Found

Error: The requested address '/opauth-complete' was not found on this server.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Config/routes.phpの記述を変えたりいろいろ試したのですがうまくいきません。
どこが悪いのでしょうか？

Comment: となると6,7が怪しいですね。Opauthで処理した結果が`/opauth-complete`に送られるので、そのルート定義とコントローラーが作成できていればいいはずなのですが…[cakephp-opauthのサンプル](https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-opauth/tree/sample-app)も参考に、その辺りを再度確認してみていただけますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます
確認してみます。
その前に基本的な質問ですが
http://サーバ名/auth/facebookを実行して
の遷移するのはhttp://サーバ名/users/opauth-completeでしょうか？
だとして、エラーから判断すると
http://サーバ名/opauth-completeに遷移させようとしている動きに見えます。
しかし6,7でopauth-completeのスペルを変えてもエラーは'/opauth-complete'と出てきます。
どこで設定しているのでしょうか？

Comment: [`OpauthAppController.php`](https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-opauth/blob/master/Controller/OpauthAppController.php%23L111)にありました。6,7はあくまで遷移した結果のリクエストを受け取る処理なので、遷移元とは別です。

Comment: 解決しました
原因は６番の追加場所を一番下に追加していたのですが、
サンプルと同じ場所に追加したところ動作しました。

大変参考になりました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @WESUEK 本回答で解決した場合には回答の承認をよろしくお願いします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

具体的にどう動かないのか書いてないので想像による答えですが、
テストサイトがlocalhostなのが問題なのではないでしょうか。

OAuthのプロトコルの解説では認証結果をOAuth Server(この場合facebook)からOAuth Client(この場合あなたが動かしているlocalhost)に返すようです。
でも、localhostでは通知のしようがないですね。

この辺が問題なのではないかと思います。

Comment: `http://localhost/`というホスト名が入力チェックでエラーとなる可能性はありますが、リダイレクトを処理するのはサーバーではなくクライアントのためOAuthの仕様上は非公開でも問題ないです。例えばアプリ内ブラウザでは`urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`というURIが良く使われます。