# CakePHPプラグインにおけるFacebook認証について

Tags: php, cakephp, facebook

CakePHPにおいて、Facebookでのログイン機能を実装しようとしているのですが上手くいきません。

http://shigurui.kirscheweb.com/?p=136
[CakePHPにおけるFacebook認証について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6422/cakephp%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8Bfacebook%E8%AA%8D%E8%A8%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)

上記のサイト通りに進めたのですが、

> Error: Class 'Opauth' not found   
>   File: /ドメイン名/app/Plugin/Opauth/Controller/OpauthAppController.php   
>   Line: 139

と表示されてしまいます。

ちなみにOpauthAppController.phpの139行目のコードは

```
$this->Opauth = new Opauth( $config, $run );
```

でした。

もし何かお分かりの方は是非ご教授下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく所定の場所にOpauth本体が存在していません。

app/Plugin/Opauth/Vendor/Opauth/ にライブラリが存在することを期待していますが、githubからのダウンロードでは中身が空のはずです。

https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-opauth に書いてある通り、インストールはレポジトリからcloneして取得後、プラグインのディレクトリで`git submodule update --init`を実行して、Opauth本体を取得する必要があります。（もしくはcomposerでインストールですね。

もしくは、https://github.com/opauth/opauth からOpauth本体をダウンロードして、app/Plugin/Opauth/Vendor/Opauth/ に配置してください。

ただし、ダウンロードでは依存関係が正しくできない可能性がありますので、gitかcomposerによる取得をお勧めします。